# Javascript can I turn const to function with output

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I'm learning javascript now and I had an idea while I was working can I change this :

```
const x = this.props.form.getFieldValue('product_gender')
console.log(x)
```

Into something like :

```
this.props.form.getFieldValue('product_gender', x => console.log(x))
```

Forgive me if sound stupid but I'm new to javascript.
thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please tell that you expect to happen?

Comment: @MaheerAli I want to be able to directly manipulate the value without assigning `const`

Comment: You need to change how getFieldValue is implement in such a case

Comment: `directly manipulate the value` which value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code snippet is using the "callback" pattern, commonly only used when the function itself is *asynchronous* (i.e. it doesn't return its result immediately, but instead has to go do some background work, and then eventually return that result).

It therefore only works if the specific API in question supports that pattern.

If you merely want to avoid assigning to a variable, just do:

```
console.log(this.props.form.getFieldValue('product_gender'));
```

Comment: That's what I suggested too, but it apparently isn't what OP wants. The question is very unclear ATM

Comment: Not what I'm looking for but I understood the concept that I need to change the structure of the  `this.props.form.getFieldValue`

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner then what _are_ you looking for?  Why do you think you want (or need) to use that pattern?   It offers no benefits unless your `getFieldValue` function is asynchronous.

Comment: @Alnitak because sometimes I can't declare a `const` inside JSX in react so I just wanted a way to get that value.

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner and do what with that value?  This sounds like you're asking the wrong question, and need to ask a new one that shows this _in the context of React_.   See also "XY questions".

Answer (score 0):

Just actually change your variable definition:

```
const x = this.props.form.getFieldValue('product_gender', x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I don't want to declare a `const`

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner But you just said in the comment on my answer that you *do* want the variable.

Comment: so you just want to run the `this.props.form.getFieldValue` function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need to change the `getFieldValue` function definition to accept a call back and run it for you.
Your `getFieldValue` function should be defined like:

```
function getFieldValue(productName, callback){
  // do something with the productName
  const returnValue = calculateYourReturnValue()
  // call the callback function
  callback(returnValue)
  return returnValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate your value before using it, but can't declare a const in JSX, then define a function to manipulate it. This is simple and straightforward:

```
doSomethingWithGender(gender) {
    return gender + "some extra text";
}

render() {
    return <div>
        { this.doSomethingWithGender(this.props.form.getFieldValue('product_gender')) }
    </div>
}
```